# JUnit test for System.out.println/System.err.println

Tags: java, junit, system.out

I have to write tests for an application and Im trying to write a juint test for somthing that is printed on the console.
The application has -->

```
System.err.println("Username cannot be empty");
```

This is what I have done so far :

```
ByteArrayOutputStream errContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
System.setErr(new PrintStream(errContent));
//left username empty and pressed login
assertEquals("Username cannot be empty", errContent.toString());
```

But I get `ComparisonFailure`

```
expected <Username cannot be empty[]> 
but was <Username cannot be empty[
]>

//difference of next line.
```

Anyone know how to solve this ?
Thanks.

EDIT : Tried `assertEquals("Username cannot be empty\n", errContent.toString());`

Now I get :

```
expected <Username cannot be empty[]
> 
but was <Username cannot be empty[
]
>
```

Comment: The real question is why you are testing java standard library methods at all. IMO a test shouldn't fail because someone decides to change an error message.

Comment: What you are missing in your test is, that  `System.err.println()` has a linefeed at the end. Change `assertEquals("Username cannot be empty", errContent.toString());` to  `assertEquals("Username cannot be empty\n", errContent.toString());`

Comment: @Quirliom We dont at work, But this is for a class I'm taking and the application is given to us with console outputs to make tests for.

Comment: @sakshik12 You could have a look at [System Rules](http://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules/) which helps you testing such output. Disclaimer: I'm the author of that library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are missing in your test is, that `System.err.println()` has a linefeed at the end. Change `assertEquals("Username cannot be empty", errContent.toString());` to `assertEquals("Username cannot be empty"+System.getProperty("line.separator"), errContent.toString());`

Comment: @wero Thanks for the improvement. Have chnaged my answer

Comment: @Jens `System.getProperty("line.separator")` works too. Thanks. :)

Comment: @sakshik12 That is the better way, with this you are OS independend